# what type of vpn is there if we specify only VPN?

Tags: security, vpn

I had seen tutorials and studied about VPN but now one confusing point which is into my mind that is if somewhere VPN is written, is it a SSL VPN or IPSec VPN?

My understanding is that there are two types of VPN : SSL VPN and IPSec VPN

SSL VPN can be used without VPN Client eg KProxy.

and IPSec VPN requires a VPN client eg OpenVPN.

SSL VPN only gives limited access to n/w while IPSec gives full n/w access

Also implementing IPSec means using IPSec VPN?

Also Does SSL VPN and HTTPS are different?

**Edit:** **Follow Up question**

regular system-level VPNs with a regular client app" i need more clarification on this..system level vpn you mean to say built in vpn in system? with a regular client app means VPN Client??

So you mean to say SSL VPN can be used in VPN Client as well as In-browser but IPSec VPN can only be implemented using VPN Client..

Answer (score 0):

> SSL VPN can be used without VPN Client eg KProxy.

"SSL VPN" appears to have two different meanings:

- It can mean in-browser web-proxy-based "VPNs",
- but it can *also* mean regular system-level VPNs with a regular client app, which just happen to use a protocol that is based on SSL/TLS.

> and IPSec VPN requires a VPN client eg OpenVPN.

OpenVPN doesn't use IPsec. (Its protocol is actually partially based on SSL/TLS.)

> SSL VPN only gives limited access to n/w while IPSec gives full n/w access

As mentioned in the 1st paragraph: "SSL VPN" often means two different things.

If you're talking about in-browser webapp gateways – yes, they only let you access certain HTTP(S)-based webapps and not the whole network.

If you're talking about system-level SSL/TLS-based VPNs – no, they connect you to the network at IP level and give full access if permitted.

> if somewhere VPN is written, is it a SSL VPN or IPSec VPN?

System-level vs in-browser? If not specified, then the term usually refers to system-level VPNs which carry whole IP packets. (In-browser "VPNs" do not actually let you access a network, they're more like webapp gateways.)

Protocol type? It could be either. It could even be neither. If it's not specified, then the type is not relevant to the discussion, all that matters is that it's *a* VPN.

> Also implementing IPSec means using IPSec VPN?

Not necessarily. IPSec can also be used for securing direct host-to-host connections, without any internal IP addresses or such.

> Also Does SSL VPN and HTTPS are different?

If you're talking about in-browser webapp gateways: no, they're called "SSL VPNs" *because* they use regular HTTPS. (They're just websites.)

If you're talking about system-level "SSL" VPNs: it varies. They *often* use SSL/TLS as the base, although they do not use HTTP, or only use it for the initial handshake.

For example, Cisco AnyConnect uses HTTPS (and therefore TLS) for the initial login handshake, then switches to DTLS (TLS-over-UDP) for the actual data transfer.

Comment: regular system-level VPNs with a regular client app" i need more clarification on this..system level vpn you mean to say built in vpn in system? with a regular client app means ??

Then is this difference valid if i specify you SSL VPN is system-level VPNs with any VPN client app and IPSec using any VPN client app..I am not talking in terms of security or features in both types